# How to read the response from the HTTPClient

Tags: java, httpclient

I am doing work around HTTPClient to send the POST request and get the response. I am getting the response code is OK.

I want to read few contents from that response `HttpEntity entity =response.getEntity();`
I am printing that response on console `System.out.println(EntityUtils.toString(entity));`.

it's printing `{"created_at":"2011-12-01T07:56:50+00:00","type":"sample","id":29,"status":"received"}`

I want to read the `id` from the above string,.

Any one can help how to retrieve the id from the entity.

Thanks in advance..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The data is [JSON](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/JSON) data.

You can go to [json.org](http://json.org/) and download [JSONObject](http://www.json.org/java/index.html).

You can do this,

```
JSONObject json = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(entity));
int id = json.getInt("id");
```

Comment: Hi Elite, I am using `net.sf.json.JSONObject`, its giving compilation error at line `JSONObject json = new JSONObject(EntityUtils.toString(entity));` constructor for String is undefined.

Comment: I'm not using `net.sf.json.JSONObject` but `org.json.JSONObject` in this example.

Comment: Yes, download the code from Github's download [`link`](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-java/downloads) directly. I downloaded the ZIP file.

Comment: I am getting `Attempted read from closed stream.` exception. I didnt used any Stream here

Comment: You have to open a new SO question for this new problem.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that you response is JSON one. can you use a JSON library, [Jackson](http://jackson.codehaus.org/) for example?

Answer (score 0):

this way is not very efficent but you can try it also.

```
BufferedReader  br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(method.getResponseBodyAsStream()));
        String readLine;
        while(((readLine = br.readLine()) != null)) {
          System.err.println(readLine);
      }

if(readLine.indexOf(",") > -1 && readLine.indexOf(":") > -1)
String id = (readLine.split(",")[2]).split(":")[1];
```